# Magento Custom Options

Tags: magento

I have two type of custom options in my product. One is with text boxes and the other with drop down/ checkbox. I want to display dropdown/  checkbox custom option just after the tier pricing area of the product detail page. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: you have to edit the template for this. Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the template/view file(catalog/product/view.phtml) under the current theme directory.